# Как можно настроить игнорируемые символы при считывании из файла?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, потоки-данных, ввод

Я применяю оператор `>>` для считывания данных из файла, и насколько я понял он игнорирует все невидимые символы, как можно это настроить если мне нужно чтобы он игнорировал все кроме завершения строки?

Ps: вопрос возможно тривиальный, но ответа я не нашел

Comment: Можно использовать input filter для boost.iostreams.

Answer (score 3):

Отдельные символы - не получится. Либо всё, либо ничего :) - ну, в отношении пробельных символов. Советую не игнорировать все символы

```
stream >> noskipws;
```

а потом просто отсеивать ненужное самостоятельно.